# Why is the TensorFlow result of a simple regression far away from its input?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network

I have a simple regression training data as below. I want to train the net in TensorFlow, and input `[1 0 1]` again (which is same as example 3) into the net, which should give me something closed to 1 (say 0.99).

[image]

Now here's my TensorFlow code (in Python 3). I used a linear layer, and then a Sigmoid. I used mean square loss. Please note that in the last few lines I input `[1 0 1]` to test the model's prediction power. I just got `0.5015` only, which is far away from my expectation (i.e. `0.99`).

**Version 1: TensorFlow Code:**

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

batch_xs=np.array([[0,0,1],[1,1,1],[1,0,1],[0,1,1]])
batch_ys=np.array([[0],[1],[1],[0]])

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 3])
W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([3, 1]))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1]))

y = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.matmul(x, W) + b)
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 1])

mean_square_loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(y_ - y)) 

learning_rate = 0.05

train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(mean_square_loss)
sess = tf.Session()
tf.global_variables_initializer().run(session=sess)

sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: batch_xs, y_: batch_ys})

x0=np.array([[1.,0.,1.]])
x0=np.float32(x0)
y0=tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.matmul(x0,W) + b)

print('%.15f' % sess.run(y0))
```

Why is the result far away from the expected value? If I just use Numpy instead of TensorFlow, the following 9-line code can achieve the output of `0.9936`.

**Version 2: Numpy Code:**

```
from numpy import exp, array, random, dot
training_set_inputs = array([[0, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1]])
training_set_outputs = array([[0, 1, 1, 0]]).T
random.seed(1)
synaptic_weights = 2 * random.random((3, 1)) - 1
for iteration in range(10000):
output = 1 / (1 + exp(-(dot(training_set_inputs, synaptic_weights))))
synaptic_weights += dot(training_set_inputs.T, (training_set_outputs - output) * output * (1 - output))
print(1 / (1 + exp(-(dot(array([1, 0, 1]), synaptic_weights)))))
```

How can I fix my TensorFlow code in version 1 so make the result closed to 0.99? Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your tensorflow code `sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: batch_xs, y_: batch_ys})` updates/train your weights. Note that you run this only once with a learning rate of 0.05. But in your numpy code, you run 10000 iterations which is equivalent to doing

```
for i in range(10000):
    sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: batch_xs, y_: batch_ys})
```

You should get around 0.95 as result. If you increase the learning rate to 1 as it seems to be done on numpy code you should get expected behavior (0.99).